# Package for prevention of sql injection

Tags: plsql

Is there any pl/sql package which is already written to handle all the scenearios which prevents SQL Injection.Please let me know if any one aware such package.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Prepared Statements

Comment: Thanks for reply , I am looking for a package that validates user inputs. Like checks for only alpha numeric and special symbols etc etc
It would be great helpful if package exits to check all scenarios

Comment: Hibernate might have something to do that. I am not sure.
http://www.hibernate.org/

Answer (score 4):

just use prepared statements in PL/SQL.  That will protect against sql injections

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply , I am looking for a package that validates user inputs. Like checks for only alpha numeric and special symbols etc etc It would be great helpful if package exits to check all scenarios –

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you want an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for applications that use the database more than a PostgreSQL package.  Or at least encapsulate your code in a function to provide parameterization.

Think about it this way.  SQL injection works by turning invalid input into malicious (but valid) SQL.  How would the database be able to determine anything else as far as whether or not it's valid SQL?  And if it could tell otherwise in all cases, why wouldn't it just do that by default instead of requiring you to use a certain package?